# 日本語に違和感:「四分の一」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

ユーザーを信用度順に表示するページ（以下）では、「今週」「今月」「四分の一」「今年」「すべて」と信用度の獲得期間を選択できる。しかし、「四分の一」という日本語に違和感有り。
訳すとしたら「**今期**」が良いと思う。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「今四半期」じゃないですかね。「今期」だと通年という意味にもなり「今年」と同義になってしまいます。

Comment: そうですね。ただ今週、今月、今年と二語なので、今期がバランスが良いかと思いました。正確性を考えると今四半期が良いですね。

Comment: @koron ツールチップはありますか？あったら、「今期」にして、ツールチップに四半期を説明したらどうですか？

Comment: @jmac 一目でわかる正確さが重視されるならば「今四半期」が好ましいです。曖昧さを残してデザイン/見た目を優先するならばツールチップでも良いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「今四半期」に改正しました。次回のビルドに適用します。